# OpenGL inconsistent vbo uploading

Tags: c, opengl

I am writing an OpenGL 3.3 C application in Windows 10. I have it working most of the time. Some times, the mesh's vbo doesn't hold the correct data. Other times, it does. There are no changes in code.

I tried restarting the computer and updated the graphics driver. I've ran it in RenderDoc to make sure I am doing things in the correct order.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh->vao);
glBindVertexArray(mesh->vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->verts);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->verts);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * data->vertCount * 2, &data->verts[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->ebo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * data->indicieCount, &data->indicies[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And then to render. Please note that render->meshes[i]->count has been set to the indicie count

```
glBindVertexArray(render->meshes[i]->vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, render->meshes[i]->count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

The vertex and indicie data should be correctly uploaded and stored to OpenGL. When viewed in RenderDoc, vbo data is partially/completely incorrect. I had some for loops before hand print out the data to verify the incoming data. The data is always correct before upload.

Comment: Is the data actually rendering correctly?

Comment: When it the data is uploaded correctly, yes. When it doesn't, no. It just draws a random triangle, filling in the missing data.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question in any way, but "indicie" isn't the correct word. Singular it's "index" and plural it's "indices," i.e. data->indexCount or data->indices.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yea I just read that.

Comment: @JeremyMoyes Probably the dynamic memory is accessed out of bounds, when initializing `data->verts` or `data->indicies`.

Comment: Posted code looks okay, are those only buffers in the whole program? If not,can you make sure that you manually unbind the VAO and then VBO+IBO after initialization?  Is `render->meshes[i]->count` equal to `data->indicieCount`?  Without more code I don't have anything better. Are you really really sure that `data->verts` is correct before the call?

Comment: @Quimby, the data is correct. I had for loops printing out the data right before the OpenGL calls

Answer (score 0):

I think @Rabbid76 had the right idea. Even though my C function had access to the data buffers, OpenGL did not always have access. Copying data from the original data buffers into new data buffers, which was allocated inside of the C function, fixed the problem.

EDIT:
Even though the C buffers where being displayed properly, the buffers themselfs where already freed by the time where uploaded.